# Computing linear components of a reducible variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algorithms

For $i=1,\dotsc,m$ let $f_i$ be polynomials in $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, where $k$ is some field.
Consider the affine variety $V = V(f_1, \dotsc, f_n)$, i.e. the set of points $x$ such that $f_i(x) = 0$.
$V$ admits a unique irreducible minimal decomposition as $V = \bigcup_{j=1}^p V_j$, where $V_j$ are irreducible varieties, which can algorithmically be computed using e.g. Macaulay2.
Is there an algorithm to compute the linear components $V_j$ only, i.e. those given by linear equalities, without computing the full decomposition?